# What is the best service/tool to put short audio clips on a website so users can click and listen immediately?

Tags: audio, web

I'm making a **foreign language flashcard website** in which I want to have **100s** of short **3-10** second **audio** files available for users to **click and listen**.

So I am looking for a tool/service such as **YouTube** or **[Screenr.com](http://screenr.com/F7g)** but for **audio** which e.g.:

- allows me to easily **upload** multiple kinds of audio files: **mp3**, wav, etc.
- easy to **manage** them online (delete, replace)
- has a simple, **small player** (e.g. flash) that integrates nicely into any site

Or has anyone built something like this with **Silverlight**, e.g. where I could send the name of an mp3 file as a parameter in the object element?

Answer (score 1):

For 3-10 second sound files, you can just serve them as any other file. If you have 100 of them, it will not amount to much storage. They are easily transmitted over http.

I don't think you need a service or site for that amount of data.  There's [a jQuery plugin that plays sound](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demo-01.htm).  Embed that into your web pages and you're done.